# Regular expression match all except first occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match all occurrences of a dot (.) except the first one.

For example if the source is:
 aaa.bbb.ccc..ddd

the expression should match the dots after bbb and ccc but not the dot after aaa. In other works it should match all dots except the first one.

I need it for javascript regex.

Comment: What  regex  flavour?

Comment: Probably easiest just to find all and skip/strip the first one. Otherwise, maybe use a lookbehind... Do you want to get _just_ the dots (i.e. their location) or also the stuff in between?

Comment: I need it for javascript regex. Sorry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with pcre (PHP, R) you can do that:

```
\G(?:\A[^.]*\.)?+[^.]*\K\.
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM3hW3/1)

details:

```
\G # anchor for the start of the string or the position after a previous match
(?:\A[^.]*\.)?+ # start of the string (optional possessive quantifier)
[^.]* # all that is not a dot
\K    # remove all that has been matched on the left from the match result
\.    # the literal dot
```

---

With .net: *(easy since you can use a variable length lookbehind)*

```
(?<!^[^.]*)\.
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5E%5B%5E.%5D*)%5C.&i=toto.tata.tutu.titi)

---

With javascript there is no way to do it with a single pattern.

using a placeholder:

```
var result = s.replace('.', 'PLACEHOLDER')
              .replace(/\./g, '|')
              .replace('PLACEHOLDER', '.');
```

*(or replace all dots with `|` and then replace the first occurrence of `|` with a dot)*.

using split:

```
var parts = s.split('.');
var result = parts.shift() + (parts.length ? '.': '') + parts.join('|');
```

with a counter:

```
var counter = 0;
var result = s.replace(/\./g, (_) => counter++ ? '|' : '.');
```

---

With NodeJS (or any other implementation that allows lookbehinds):

```
var result = s.replace(/((?:^[^.]*\.)?(?<=.)[^.]*)\./g, "$1|");
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great for pcre and also for .NET if possessive quantifier is removed (\G(?:\A[^.]*\.)?[^.]*\K\.). Is there an option for javascript too?

Comment: @gabrielgeo: no this pattern can't be used with .NET (the main reason is that the `\K` feature doesn't exist, the other reason is that you can't use the pattern without the possessive quantifier if there is only one dot in the string). See my edit for other ways.

Answer (score 7):

One-line solution for JavaScript using arrow function (ES6):

```
'aaa.bbb.ccc..ddd'
   .replace(/\./g, (c, i, text) => text.indexOf(c) === i ? c : '|')

-> 'aaa.bbb|ccc||ddd'
```