# Replace all occurrences of a character in a string after the first one

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like

```
string s = "abc; abc bla bla ;;;;; bla bla";
```

I want to replace the all but the first `;` with a `:`. I can get the count as follows:

```
int t = s.Where(e => e.ToString() == ";").Count();
```

If I do `s.Replace(';', ':');` all the `;` are replaced with `:`. Can someone tell me how to achieve this please.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413960/regular-expression-match-all-except-first-occurence Also have the answer you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a bit of regex:

```
string s = "abc; abc bla bla ;;;;; bla bla";
var regex = new Regex("(?<!^[^;]*);");
var result = regex.Replace(s,":");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/ORZU81353