# Sanitize phone number: regular expression match all except first occurence is on first position

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

regarding to this post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413960/regular-expression-match-all-except-first-occurence" I'm wondering how to find the first occurence on a string only if it start's with a specfic character in PHP.

I would like to sanitize phonenumbers. Example bad phone number:

```
+49+12423#23492@aosd#+dasd
```

Regex to remove all "+" except first occurence.

```
\G(?:\A[^\+]*\+)?+[^\+]*\K\+
```

Problem: it should remove every "+" only if it starts with "+" not if the first occurence-position is greater than 1.

The regex to remove everything except numbers is easy:

```
[^0-9]*
```

But I don't know how to combine those two within one regex. I would just use preg_replace() twice.

Of course I would be able to use a workaround like if ($str[0] === '+') {...} but I prefer to learn some new stuff (regex :)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)|^\+)[^+]*\K\+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhcUk1/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^\+)` - either the end of the preceding successful match or a `+` at the start of string
- `[^+]*` - zero or more chars other than `+`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `\+` - a `+` char.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/q4k6U):

```php
$re = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|^\+)[^+]*\K\+/m';
$str = '+49+12423#23492@aosd#+dasd';
echo preg_replace($re, '', $str);
// => +4912423#23492@aosd#dasd
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to combine the two queries:

> *A regex to remove everything except numbers*

> *A regex to remove all "+" except first occurence*

Here is my two cents:

```
(?:^\+|\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

Replace what is matched with nothing. Here is an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Sv3RG/1)

---

- `(?:^\+|\d)` - A non-capture group to match a starting literal plus or any digit in the range from 0-9.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - Consume the previous matched characters and fail them in the rest of the matching result.
- `|` - Or:
- `.` - Any single character other than newline.

---

I'd like to think that this is a slight adaptation of what some consider *["The best regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)* where one would first try to match what you *don't* want, then use an alternation to match what you *do* want. With the use of the backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` we reverse the logic. We first match what we *do* want, exclude it from the results and then match what we *don't* want.