# How to replace every underscore after first with '/'

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column of values:

```
df1$V1 = c("5325_214424", "63325_685_2436", "573_636", "5754_23523_214235", "5634_777_19_101")
```

I would like to keep only the first underscore in every row and replace any additional underscores with a slash. Some row values may or may not have additional underscores.
So ideally I would like to end up with this:

```
df1$V1 = c("5325_214424", "63325_685/2436", "573_636", "5754_23523/214235", "5634_777/19/101")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches -

1. Split the string on `_` and paste the values back except 1st one with `/`.

```
x <- c("5325_214424", "63325_685_2436", "573_636", 
       "5754_23523_214235", "5634_777_19_101")

sapply(strsplit(x, '_'), function(x) 
       paste(x[1], paste0(x[-1], collapse = '/'), sep = '_'))

#[1] "5325_214424"  "63325_685/2436"  "573_636"  
#    "5754_23523/214235" "5634_777/19/101"
```

2. A complex regex solution using help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414387/3962914) -

```
gsub('\\G(?:\\A[^_]*_)?+[^_]*\\K_', '/', x, perl = TRUE)

#[1] "5325_214424"       "63325_685/2436"    "573_636"  
#     "5754_23523/214235" "5634_777/19/101"
```

Comment: The solutions are perfect, thank you so much.